# Angular : An unhandled exception occurred: Expected end of file, got ", "defaultProject"..."

Tags: angular

An unhandled exception occurred: Expected end of file, got ",
"defaultProject": ..." at 205:1.
See "/private/tmp/ng-CzE6Rq/angular-errors.log" for further details.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it's an Angular.json syntax error.
The error doesn't indicate which file has the problem, so definitely could use a better error message. might be, other JSON files cause similar errors